# GCP - Create Datalab instance with OS image

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-datalab

I want to create a Datalab VM instance with ubuntu on it, but the tutorials only explain how to customise the machine type, not the Operating system.  How do I create a Datalab VM with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the image used with the `--image-name` flag ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create#--image-name_image_name)). The Ubuntu image can be retrieved from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), for example. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started) where they tag an image and push it to GCR (Google Container Registry):

```
docker tag datalab gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/datalab
```

And then you can specify that image upon Datalab instance creation with the aforementioned flag:

```
datalab create --image-name=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/datalab INSTANCE_NAME
```